# Why is the link to view an employer message so small?

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, user-interface

I got a message from one of the employers on careers wanting to hire me. When I went to view the message, I went to [the "messages" tab](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/messages) and saw a listing, as one would expect.

There's a big ol' table with date, employer, subject, status, and a teeny tiny little link to view the message. Why have the link there at all? Why not just make the entire row clickable?

[screenshot http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/338/screenybf.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/338/screenybf.png)

Comment: Clearly this needs a screenshot with a freehand circle or two.

Comment: Why did you make your screenshot even harder to read than this so-called tiny link?

Answer (score 3):

I think we forgot to install [The Admiral's Pipe](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/05/12/417064.aspx) ... :)

> I was recently reminded of a story one of our development managers told me.  Before he started his career in software he was a sailor aboard a Russian sub.  Inspections by the admiral were a regular occurrence and involved a huge investment of time to clean the entire sub… As you might expect Russian admirals were fairly demanding and always *expected* to find problems.  In fact they kept looking until they found the problem however unimportant they were.  Apparently the sailors came up with a creative way address placate the admiral.  They would leave one, fairly obvious, pipe un-cleaned. The admiral would find this pipe, insist that it be cleaned and feel satisfied that he found a problem and not dig any deeper.  This practice became known as using “the Admiral’s pipe”.

Comment: So... **[status-completed]?**

Comment: I was just reading [this post the other day, at a blog called Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html), that had collected the top entries from [the old SO "New programming jargon you coined?" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined) (10k-only), and this looks suspiciously like #5, The Duck.